# Prepare a string representation of a command and then execute id

Tags: django

**Django==2.2.2**

Now I have this code:

**Model**

```
class YandexResponse(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    campaigns = models.TextField()
    ad_groups = models.TextField()
    ads = models.TextField()
    keywords = models.TextField()
    sitelinks = models.TextField()
```

**View**

```
yandex_response_record, created = YandexResponse.objects.get_or_create(id=1)

if what_to_update == "campaigns":
    yandex_response_record.campaigns=json.dumps(data)
    yandex_response_record.save()
elif what_to_update == "ad_groups":
    yandex_response_record.ad_groups=json.dumps(data)
    yandex_response_record.save()
...
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
tmp = "yandex_response_record.{}=json.dumps(data)".format(what_to_update)
execute(tmp);
yandex_response_record.save()
```

Could you tell me whether is is somehow possible? If it is not possible, could you suggest me some elegant solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use the **setattr** function as specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

> 'setattr' is the counterpart of getattr(). The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute.

So instead of checking for the value of the field passed, you can do:

```
yandex_response_record, created = YandexResponse.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
setattr(yandex_response_record, what_to_update, json.dumps(data))
yandex_response_record.save()
```

What it does is updates the field name specified in `what_to_update` as provided in `json.dumps(data)`.

Maybe it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the built-in `setattr` function.

```
setattr(yandex_response_record, what_to_update, json.dumps(data))
yandex_response_record.save()
```